# Xcode changing Swift Version : clumsy to change code line by line

Tags: swift, xcode

When I reload downloaded sample project of IOS, it finds out that `SWIFT_VERSION` is not defined. If I define `SWIFT_VERSION` as `4.2` or else , it turns out that I have to change the code line one by one, click by click specified by the Swift Compiler Error Messages.

Is there any method or extension that we can replace all those code lines?

Comment: Set the version to the lowest value and compile the code. If it succeeds use the migrator. If it fails you have to do it manually. It’s worth it, you will learn a lot and the compiler will give you some suggestions.

Comment: Is migrator an extension or built-in plugin at Xcode?

Comment: That’s the functionality which is executed when you select the *Convert to latest Swift syntax* menu item